# how to extract a number only, not any operators

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to match numbers only in a string that contain operators.
However the following regEx is also giving me operators I dnt know why? 
For example I have the string `"2X/8"` and I am trying to get rid of 8.

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(elements[i], @"\d"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Adding to numberstack:+ ", elements[i]);
    numberStack.Push(elements[i]);
}

if (i >= elements.Length - 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside the popper");
    if ((i - 2) >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numberStack.Peek());
        if (elements[i - 1].Contains("/*") && elements[i - 2].Contains("X"))
        {
            numberStack.Pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems a bit confusing to me, but I'm assuming the following (correct me if I'm wrong):

- You are trying to discover if there is a number at the beginning of your string, and extract that number
- "elements" is an array of string elements.
- "numberStack" is a stack of string elements.

If so, notice you are pushing the "elements[i]" value to the stack, which I understand contains the **whole string** of the expression you are trying to evaluate ("2X/8" as per your example), and not only the number at the start of the expression. This would explain why you are getting not only the number "2" on your result, but the whole "2X/8" value.

There are several ways to extract the numbers for an expression, and selecting one of them depends on your specific needs.

As a quick example, if you just want to extract each set of numbers from a string, you can get all matches for your regular expression inside that string and iterate through them:

```
string theExpression = "2X/8+123";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(theExpression, @"\d+");
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);

Console.ReadLine();
```

This example would print the numbers `2`, `8` and `123` from the given expression to the output.